# Toggle between GridView tables without reloading the page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, server-side

I have 4 GridView Tables.I want to toggle between them .I have 4 buttons ,each for one table.Hiding and showing tables didn't work as firstly,the page reloads whenever i press the buttons and secondly i cant put all the 4 tables at exact same location.So,is there a way by which I can toggle between the tables without reloading the page.

Comment: You basically have 4 Options, in order of ease of implementation: 1) Load all the tables on page load, hide the ones you don't want visible then use javascript to hide and display the tables. Depending on the size of the tables your initial page load could take a big hit. 2) Use [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) to do a partial refresh and load the table you want. 3) Use custom AJAX to fetch the table. 4) A hybrid version of option 1 and 3, load the initial table then load the subsequent hidden tables in the background.